# Adding breakpoint to javascript in xcode

Tags: cordova

I have created a phonegap app for ios.I need to add breakpoints to the javascript functions that i have written in index.html file. How do i do that? please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You could do it with Safari Develop Menu on iOS.

Run your application in an (iPhone/iPad) simulator.  Open Safari, go to develop menu, sub menu to that simulator and select your loaded page to debug.  It should open web inspector where you can go to your JS file and set breakpoints.

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/Debugging-in-PhoneGap

Answer (score 2):

You can't put breakpoint in xcode for javascript. If you want to debug your application, you can do that with chrome in developper mode. With it you can access your js file and put breakpoint.